# Exception filter triggers CA2202?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, compiler-warnings, code-analysis, c#-6.0

I have a function that, boiled down, looks like this:

```
public static string Merge(string xml1, string xml2)
{
   try
   {
      var doc1 = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml1));
      var doc2 = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml2));

      // these "die" by throwing InvalidOperationException
      var root1 = GetElementOrDie(doc1, Names.RootElementName);
      var root2 = GetElementOrDie(doc2, Names.RootElementName);

      foreach (var element in root2.Elements())
         root1.Add(element);

      return doc1.ToString();
   }
   catch (Exception e) when (!(e is InvalidOperationException))
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message, e);
   }
}
```

Under Visual Studio 2015, this generates code analysis warning CA2202:

> Object 'root2.Elements().GetEnumerator()' can be disposed more than
>   once in method 'XmlProcessor.Merge(string, string)'. To avoid
>   generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call
>   Dispose more than one time on an object.

If I remove the `when` clause, the warning goes away.

What's going on here? Is it right to be warning me?

For reference:

```
private static XElement GetElementOrDie(XContainer container, XName elementName)
{
   var element = container.Element(elementName);
   if (element == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   return element;
}
```

Comment: This looks more like an issue with code analysis. I would rather ignore the warning.

Comment: I've also seen CA incorrectly complain about not disposing an object when using the null conditional operator like `disposable?.Dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with Code Analysis and I would suppress it. If I convert the loop from:

```
foreach (var element in root2.Elements())
   root1.Add(element);
```

to this to expose the enumerator it's complaining about explicitly:

```
var enumerator = root2.Elements().GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    XElement item = enumerator.Current;
    root1.Add(item);
}
```

Then `CA2202` isn't thrown anymore, even with the `when` filer on the exception.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but it's not surprising that that change stops the warning since `Dispose` isn't being called on the enumerator at all anymore. I think to answer this definitively would require inspecting the disassembly and confirming that there is no path through the code that would result in `Dispose` being called more than once. A quick check with LinqPad shows just one call being generated, but I'm not enough of an IL guru to be sure there isn't some jump or loop that would result in that instruction being executed more than once.

Comment: That said, the only `CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope` errors I got with the second version were on your `StringReader`s still.